# Assign new custom object from deque c++

Tags: c++

I currently have:

```
deque<Job> jobs;
jobs.push_back(Job(1));
```

Where Job is a custom class I made (really simple, just has a job number), and what I want to do is the following:

```
Job currentJob = jobs.pop_front();
```

However, this gives me errors. How do I accomplish assigning the popped Job to a new Job?

Comment: Please include some of the error messages.

Comment: `pop_front()` is a void function

Comment: are you trying to assign a Job value with a destroyed object in the list? it is not possible, is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from documentation:

> void pop_front();
>
> Delete first element
>   Removes the first element in the deque container, effectively reducing its size by one.
>
> This destroys the removed element.

```
 pop_front()
```

destroys the object, you may need to try:

```
Job currentJob = jobs.front();
jobs.pop_front(); //remove the object from container and reduce size by 1
```

See [std::deque::pop_front](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/pop_front/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this

```
Job currentJob = jobs.front();
jobs.pop_front();
```